# How to understand the execution sequence of SELECT and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I googled the question and all answers said SELECT was executed before ORDER BY. But the simple example below (using MySQL and sakila database) gives the correct sorted results. Obviously, ORDER BY is not executed after SELECT, as customer_id is not selected by SELECT. Can anybody explain what happened?

`SELECT rental_date FROM rental ORDER BY customer_id LIMIT 10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Bear in mind that the execution sequence is a general rule, and how any given query is parsed may vary, depending on indexes, caches, etc.

But with that said, if you're trying to understand how your query was parsed under those general guidelines, it would be something like this:

General execution sequence:

- `FROM` clause: Pull table `rental` into memory as preliminary result set.
- `WHERE` clause: No filtering applied; display full result set.
- `SELECT` clause: Only display column `rental_date` in final result set. (The full table still exists in memory.)
- `GROUP BY` clause: No grouping or aggregation applied.
- `HAVING` clause: No filtering by aggregated values applied.
- `ORDER BY` clause: Sort the displayed result set using the column `customer_id`.

The engine may sort all of the results, but may only sort enough results to fulfill the `LIMIT` clause before displaying the number of rows requested in that clause.

Comment: @GL_Li . . . I disagree with your accepting this answer.  As the other two answers explain, there is no specified *execution* sequence in a SQL query.  This answer just continues your misunderstanding.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I tried to make the answer as qualified as possible, but if you're saying that it's entirely invalid, then I'm afraid I misunderstood as well. Should I take this down?

Answer (score 2):

There's no execution sequence in SQL, at all.

SQL is a *declarative* language, not an *imperative* one. You are trying to establish a parallel between SQL and imperative languages such Java, or Python, or C#... but there isn't one.

Each SQL engine is free to rewrite/rephrase your query (at will), to execute in any order, and even to change its strategy over time, as long as it returns the data **according to the predicates that constraint the result set**.

That's it. Not more, not less.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, `ORDER BY` is not executed after SELECT, as `customer_id` is not selected by `SELECT`.

You are misinterpreting the concepts here. The `select` clause defines which columns will appear in the resultset, and the `order by` clause defines how rows will be ordered.

How the database actually executes the query, and in which sequence the different clauses are taken into account, is a different matter. SQL is a descriptive language: you tell the database *which* results that you want, not *how* it should proceed.

If you want the query to return the `customer_id`, then add it to the `select` clause:

```
SELECT customer_id, rental_date FROM rental ORDER BY customer_id LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: My question is: what is the meaning of execution sequence as specified by standard anwers?